# Bookauthor field is not displayed in APA reference style

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I want to cite a foreword of a book. So when I input the details as a @incollection entry, book authors didn't appear in the reference list. This works for authoryear reference style. But not for APA. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{csquotes}


   \usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
   \DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}


  \usepackage{filecontents}
  \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @incollection{Author1976,
    address = {Cambridge},
    author = {Author, A},
    booktitle = {Book title},
    bookauthor = {Bookauthor, A and Bookauthor, B},
    pages = {1--10},
    publisher = {University Press},
    title = {{Foreword title}},
    year = {1976}
    }
    \end{filecontents}

    \bibliography{\jobname.bib}

    \begin{document}
    \cite{Author1976}
    \printbibliography

    \end{document}
```

The output should looks like below.

[image]

Comment: What should the output look like? I think you will have to patch the incollection (and inbook) driver to do this. Which can be done using the `xpatch` package and `xpatchbibdriver`

Comment: Actually, you might have to modify the `maintitle+booktitle` macro. This might be better I think. Again `xpatch` and `\xpatchbibmacro` could be used. I'll do an actual answer if you show me what the expected output is.

Comment: It won't really help with the problem at hand, but it could be that you actually have an `@inbook`(or even a `@suppbook`) entry instead of an `@incollection`.

Comment: I tried both @inbook and $suppbook. It didn't work with APA style.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said, it won't help with your specific problem, still conceptually one of the two is better suited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. (I've used `@suppbook`, since @moewe is right that this makes more sense—still works with `@incollection` though.

The name format for `bookauthor` is set using `DeclareNameAlias{bookauthor}{apanames}` and `\xpatchbibmacro` is used to insert the `bookauthor` after *in* in the `maintitle+booktitle` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@suppbook{Stone1976,
  address = {Cambridge, England},
  author = {Stone, R},
  booktitle = {Social Accounting for Development Planning with Special Reference to {Sri Lanka}},
  bookauthor = {Pyatt, G and Roe, A},
  pages = {xvi-xxxi},
  publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
  title = {Foreword},
  subtitle = {The Development of Economic Data Systems},
  year = {1976}
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareNameAlias{bookauthor}{apanames}
\xpatchbibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{in}%
}
{%
  \usebibmacro{in}%
  \ifnameundef{bookauthor}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
     \setunit*{\addcomma\space}}%
}{}{}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\cite{Stone1976}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Could you please explain bit more about this macro editing. Because I haven't tried something before.

Comment: Sure! Have a look at `apa.bbx` and find the `maintitle+booktitle` macro. Notice that it inserts *in* then goes straight to `maintitle` and then `booktitle`. `\xpatchbibmacro` inserts the `bookauthor` after the *in*. (Actually, I've been a bit lazy... I think that this will generate problems, looking at things more closely). Probably `bookauthor` should be inserted *before* `booktitle` and it should be wrapped in an `\ifnameundef{bookauthor}{}{}` to ensure that punctuation isn't stuffed up. I had to modify the bookauthor macro also to print the names in the right format. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Hmm. Actually I'm not so sure. It annoys me that `biblatex` doesn't have `mainauthor` and associated variant fields. I think I'll leave it after `usebibmacro{in}`. I'll change the name format in a more clever way though. Edit coming up.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, the name order is wrong here.
It is not

**last name, [short] first name** but

**[short] first name, last name**

To change this, replace `\DeclareNameAlias{bookauthor}{apanames}` with `\DeclareNameAlias{bookauthor}{apaauthor}`.

In the standard biblatex.def, the NameAlias of *bookauthor* and *bybookauthor* also refers to *author* respectively *byauthor* (that also refers to *author*) (which is *default*).

(can't comment, so I had to post this as new answer)