# bookauthor field missing using style=apa

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I was very confused to find that biblatex-apa (style=apa) does not spit out the bookauthor field. Instead, it just uses the booktitle field.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}

    \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
        @inbook{test2021,
        bookauthor = {Doe, John and Doe, Jane},
        booktitle = {This is our book},
        author = {Joe, GI},
        title = {I appear in your book},
        pages = {110-120},
        number = {144},
        publisher = {Fantasy Press},
        address = {Mars},
        year = {2021}
        }
    \end{filecontents}
    \bibliography{\jobname.bib}

    \begin{document}
        \parencite{test2021}
        \printbibliography
    \end{document}
```

[image: Results]

I tried using [THIS](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341009/bookauthor-field-is-not-displayed-in-apa-reference-style) But without any luck.

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: In my experience, it is fairly unusual to have a bona fide `@inbook` entry. Most of those entries are actually `@incollection`s (the difference being that an `@incollection` appears in a collection, *edited* by editors who collect papers written by different sets of authors, whereas an `@inbook` is a chapter of a `@book` written in its entirety by the same set of authors) or could be better handled by citing the entire `@book`. Have you checked if `@incollection` might not be the better type here?

Comment: ... If you have a real-world example of a bona fide `@inbook` that is not handled according to APA rules in `biblatex-apa`, open a bug report at https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues giving your real world example and ideally reference to the specific APA rules in the manual that show how the entry should be referenced.

Comment: Re the difference between `@inbook` and `@incollection` see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/390410/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/450516/35864. (Of course it is not possibly to say anything useful about a dummy entry like the one in the question. If you can give the real-world example we could check which type is more appropriate.)

Comment: After reviewing your answers, toying with the `@incollection` type and rereading the biblatex.pdf, I have come to the conclusion that the `@incollection` type is indeed what I need. It is strange however, that with other styles provided with (some of?) the core biblatex packages, e.g. _authoryear_ `@inbook` will print the _bookauthor_ field.

Comment: `biblatex-apa` is not based on any of the standard `biblatex` styles and may thus differ from what other styles do in details even in the data model. I'm guessing that the examples in the APA manual never require a `bookauthor`, so the case is simply undefined in APA style and thus not really catered for in `biblatex-apa`. (As I wrote above, if you can find anything relevant in the APA manual that would probably be something to post on the bugtracker.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, it is fairly unusual to have a *bona fide* `@inbook` entry. Most of those entries are actually `@incollections` (the difference being that an `@incollection` appears in a collection edited by editors who collect papers written by different sets of authors, whereas an `@inbook` is a chapter/section/part of a `@book` written in its entirety by the same set of authors) or could be better handled by citing the entire `@book`. For more on `@incollection` vs `@inbook` see [Modifying InBook Reference with Chicago-Annote style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/390410/35864) and [My @inbook does not shows the editor and the title of the book?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/450516/35864).

`biblatex-apa` implements APA style as closely as possible. If there is no provision for *bona fide* `@inbook` entries in the APA publication manual, the expected output for those entries is sort of undefined. `biblatex-apa` may then not handle those entries according to your expectation/interpolation of APA guidelines.

If you have a real `@inbook` entry which is not correctly handled by `biblatex-apa` as far as rules in the APA publication manual are considered, please open a bug report at https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues with the real-world example you have in mind and ideally reference to the relevant sections of the APA manual.